# Avoid graphics artefact when switching tab in TabControl and doing math (.NET)

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics, tabcontrol

I have a form with a TabControl in a Visual Studio project, with 4 tabs.

When I load the form, I prepare only 3 tabs.

If the user switches to the 4th tab, I have to do some math before display data in the tab.

When switching I experience some graphics artefact, as show below:

[image]

*(don't look at the blurried, look at the while stripe in the middle and the cutted graphics on the right)*

I tried Suspending Layout before doing the math but probably in the TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged the drawing has already begun.
And no, there is no changING event.

How can I solve this issue? **Possibly without using a separate thread.**

Comment: Then tag it winform.   This is UI question.

Comment: Does the artifact correct itself after your calculation completes or are there residual artifacts?

Comment: It corrects after calculation. Note that the calculation only takes 0.4-0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say that the artifact corrects itself after your calculation completes, this is most likely due to the fact that you are not giving the UI thread a chance to update the screen because you're spending the CPU doing your calculation.  You will likely need to use some sort of threading to resolve the issue.

Windows Forms contains a nice [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) control which can make this kind of task pretty simple.  Just drag the control from the Toolbox onto your form designer and then create event handlers for the `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events.  Put your calculations in the `DoWork` handler and any updates to the UI that need to happen after the calculation completes in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler (its important to note that you should not access any UI elements from the `DoWork` handler).

Here is a brief code sample:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private MyCalculationState _state;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      _state = new MyCalculationState();

      // Do some calculations
      _state.Value = 5;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      // Update the UI after calculations are complete
      textBox1.Text = _state.Value.ToString();
    }
  }
```